# SDK for getting metric statistics

Tags: azure, go

AWS Cloudwatch has an api which allows fetching metric statistics:

- [CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics REST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html)
- [CloudWatch GetMetricStatistics Go implementation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cloudwatch/#CloudWatch.GetMetricStatistics)

I have been able to find the REST definition for azure which appears to have similar functionality:

- [Azure list metric values REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list)

but I can't find the Go implementation. [`azure-sdk-for-go`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go) has a lot of code in it, but I can't find the code for listing metric values.

---

Some more details:
I am trying to get status code statistics for an application gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operations you're mentioning can be found in the package:

[github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/monitor/mgmt/2018-03-01/insights](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/blob/514bddd77de93dd0349ada5fbe250077ddc619ff/services/monitor/mgmt/2018-03-01/insights/metrics.go)

In general though, if you're ever able to find a link to the REST documentation, the Azure SDK for Go can be searched for the URL of the operation. For yours in particular, I searched "/providers/micorosoft.insights/metrics" and was able to zero in on the operation.